# sql db2 - max date and 2nd max date for rolling 30 days

Tags: sql, date, dynamic, db2, max

My current statement pulls prices from a table where the population for the current price is associated with the max or most recent date found in the table. The last price for the record is the price from the 2nd max day found in the table.

How do I create a statement what pulls a rolling 30 days of past dates where the last date is always the previous day found?

```
SELECT
T1.ID
T1.DT_PRICE
T1.PRICE
T2.LAST_DT_PRICE,   
T2.LAST_PRICE

FROM    
 (SELECT    
  fpr.ID,   
  fpr.DT_PRICE, 
  fpr.PRICE 
  FROM UDBADM.PRICES fpr    

  WHERE fpr.DT_PRICE = (select max(DT_PRICE) 
                       from UDBADM.PRICES)  
    AND fpr.CD_PRICE = 'C'
 ) T1

LEFT JOIN   
  (SELECT   
   fpr2.ID, 
   fpr2.DT_PRICE AS LAST_DT_PRICE,  
   fpr2.PRICE AS LAST_PRICE 
   FROM UDBADM.PRICES fpr2  

   WHERE fpr2.DT_PRCE = (select max(DT_PRICE) 
                         from UDBADM.PRICES 
                         where DT_PRICE < (select 
                                          max(DT_PRICE) 
                                          from UDBADM.PRICES))  
   AND fpr2.CD_PRICE = 'C'
  ) T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Current output for 1 record:

```
ID     DT_PRICE    PRICE   LAST_DT_PRICE  LAST_PRICE
B5199  11/30/2016  50.3    11/29/2016     50.1
```

Expected output for 1 record with rolling 30 days:

```
ID     DT_PRICE    PRICE   LAST_DT_PRICE  LAST_PRICE
B5199  10/18/2016  50.1    10/17/2016     50
B5199  10/19/2016  50      10/18/2016     50.1
B5199  10/20/2016  49.75   10/19/2016     50
B5199  10/21/2016  49.8    10/20/2016     49.75
B5199  10/24/2016  50.12   10/21/2016     49.8
B5199  10/25/2016  50.2    10/24/2016     50.12
B5199  10/26/2016  50.25   10/25/2016     50.2
B5199  10/27/2016  50.1    10/26/2016     50.25
B5199  10/28/2016  49.8    10/27/2016     50.1
B5199  10/31/2016  49.5    10/28/2016     49.8
B5199  11/1/2016   49.2    10/31/2016     49.5
B5199  11/2/2016   50      11/1/2016      49.2
B5199  11/3/2016   50.1    11/2/2016      50
B5199  11/4/2016   50      11/3/2016      50.1
B5199  11/7/2016   49.75   11/4/2016      50
B5199  11/8/2016   49.8    11/7/2016      49.75
B5199  11/9/2016   50      11/8/2016      49.8
B5199  11/10/2016  50      11/9/2016      50
B5199  11/14/2016  50.1    11/10/2016     50
B5199  11/15/2016  50.1    11/14/2016     50.1
B5199  11/16/2016  49.8    11/15/2016     50.1
B5199  11/17/2016  49.5    11/16/2016     49.8
B5199  11/18/2016  49.2    11/17/2016     49.5
B5199  11/21/2016  48.9    11/18/2016     49.2
B5199  11/22/2016  49.8    11/21/2016     48.9
B5199  11/23/2016  50.2    11/22/2016     49.8
B5199  11/25/2016  50.2    11/23/2016     50.2
B5199  11/28/2016  50.2    11/25/2016     50.2
B5199  11/29/2016  50.1    11/28/2016     50.2
B5199  11/30/2016  50.3    11/29/2016     50.1
```

Comment: Sorry dont understand your logic. Also show us Sample Data to get that output.. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       fpr.Id
       ,fpr.DT_PRICE
       ,fpr.PRICE
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fpr.Id ORDER BY fpr.DT_PRICE) as IdRowNumber
    FROM
       UDBADM.PRICES fpr
    WHERE
       fpr.CE_PRICE = 'C'
       AND fpr.DT_PIRCE >= '10/23/2016'
)

SELECT
    c1.Id
    ,c1.DT_PRICE
    ,c1.PRICE
    ,c2.DT_PRICE as LAST_PRICE_DATE
    ,c2.PRICE as LAST_PRICE
FROM
    cte c1
    INNER JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.Id = c2.Id
    AND c1.IdRowNumber = c2.IdRowNumber + 1
```

Because you have gaps in your dates you could generate a row_number based on date and then use the row number in a self join to get the price before.  Note the INNER JOIN will give you your exact output but you may want to consider LEFT JOIN so that you will have the initial price date of 11/17/2016 represented but that is up to you.

As far as limiting to a rolling 30 days how to accomplish that will depend on what you mean by that.

If you want any prices in the last 30 days then add a where condition in the Common Table Expression which looks for DT_PRICE > current date - 30 days.

If however you want the last 30 price records regardless of dates then just flip the row_number to be DESCENDING and select the first 30 records like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       fpr.Id
       ,fpr.DT_PRICE
       ,fpr.PRICE
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fpr.Id ORDER BY fpr.DT_PRICE DESC) as IdRowNumber
    FROM
       UDBADM.PRICES fpr
    WHERE
       fpr.CE_PRICE = 'C'
)

SELECT
    c1.Id
    ,c1.DT_PRICE
    ,c1.PRICE
    ,c2.DT_PRICE as LAST_PRICE_DATE
    ,c2.PRICE as LAST_PRICE
FROM
    cte c1
    INNER JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.Id = c2.Id
    AND c1.IdRowNumber = c2.IdRowNumber - 1
WHERE
    c1.IdRowNumber <= 30
```

Comment: Hey @Matt, The first statement you posted worked great! Thank you! Where exactly should I enter the DT_PRICE date range or Max Number of RowNumbers to return? I tried entering an AND statement at the very end of CTE and said: AND fpr.DT_PIRCE >= '11/23/2016', for example to get a few days worth - I noticed one thing - If a record is new and does not have a LAST_PRICE_DATE and LAST_PRICE, it does not appear in the output. Is there a quick solution to include records that have NULLS for the LAST_PRICE_DATE and LAST_PRICE ?

Comment: @steveW you are welcome.  thanks for accepting don't forget to upvote too.  As far as where to enter the the max rows or min date that depends on what you want e.g. 30 records then use the second statement that limits the records.  If you want last 30 days then enter in the cte AND DT_PRICE, I edited that to make it a little more clear.  Hope you are all set. cheers

Comment: Just one other thing - Do you recommend appending a sub query or adjusting the and statement to OR to account for records where the last date and price is NULL? The query currently excludes any record that has a NULL last date and price.

Comment: @steveW I thought I addressed that but I would use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN in the select.  That would give you a record for the earliest DT_Price with no matching "Latest" record.  When using the IdRowNumber <= 30 if there are older prices even than the 30 days you are looking for you would still get a last price for the earliest record